# Unable to update Chrome, even after setting SD card as default installation path

Tags: updates, sd-card

I have an Alcatel Fierce 2 phone with Kit Kat. Even though I have an 8 GB SD card, when I try to update Chrome I keep getting "not enough memory check storage". I have the box checked to use my SD card as default, but no luck. Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only real solution is to clear up some space on the system 'drive' - uninstall things you don't need, media files and so on.

I typically plug my phone into a computer, move as much stuff out as possible, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it first, then downloading the latest app from the play store.

*I'm not sure about this but it would explain the insufficient storage:*
I think while updating the app becomes bigger (incremented with the new update or a whole new app?) and cleans itself up at the end of installation. So you will need more room than the size of the app.
If you uninstall the app first you will not need this extra storage.